# How to write SQL server query with "order by" and "group by" using different columns?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I want to write a query in `SQL Server` using `order by` and `group by` in the same `query` but different `columns`:

```
SELECT map.route_id FROM map GROUP BY map.route_id ORDER BY (map.orderOfcity);
```

It gives this error :

> Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>       Column "map.orderOfcity" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not    contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I realized that I have to make `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` for the same column but that doesn't suit for me, what should I do instead?

Comment: Which `orderofcity` value should it use for ordering by if there are multiple different possible ones in a group?

Comment: No it's not possible. I guess your situation is that each `route_id` correspond to a city, so simply `GROUP BY` both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `orderOfCity` is a number, you can do this:

```
SELECT map.route_id
FROM map 
GROUP BY map.route_id
ORDER BY MIN(map.orderOfcity);
```

Comment: You can do this, yes. But it will be on best-effort scenario. What the OP wants is logically not possible, unless the OP willing to change the requirement a little bit to "minimum value of different column".